# Why is Joe Biden addressed as Vice President even if he's not the current one?

Tags: united-states, president, vice-president

During interviews or debates, Joe Biden is often addressed as Mr. Vice President or referred to as Vice President Biden. This sounds very odd to my (Dutch) ears; nobody would address a former (prime) minister by a political position they no longer have. Even for royals, our [former head of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatrix_of_the_Netherlands) is now a princess and not a queen anymore.

Is there any kind of law in the United States which regulates this, or is this just some kind of tradition/habit? If the latter, how and when did it originate?

Comment: Closely related: [What is the proper title for a former U.S. President?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/47505/19301)

Comment: Voted to close, looks like a duplicate of the question linked by @divibisan

Comment: It requires me to assume that [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/47530/10072) is correct. Perhaps it is, but a little more research would be nice.

Comment: @Glorfindel there are [sources in this answer to a related question on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78969).